# access arbitrary property from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a set of nesting json object like this:

```
var obj = {
  name: "student",
  contact: {
     phone: "22222",
     fax: "33333",
     ...
  },
  ...
}
```

And I have these text fields:

```
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="contact_phone" />
<input type="text" name="contact_fax" />
...
```

Now I want to fill these fields with appropriate property from above object. My question is **how can I access anonymous property from that object?** 
For example suppose I have this jquery code:

```
 $("#formID").find("input").each(function(index) {
    fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
    var namePart = fieldName.split("_");
    //I want something like this: console.log(obj.namePart[0].namePart[1])
});
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an anonymous property.  All property values have a property name.

Comment: I think you mean `arbitrary` not `anonymous`

Comment: What's the best title for this question? I don't know, could you choose another appropriate title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `obj["propertyName"]`

```
obj[namePart[0]][namePart[1]]
```

---

```
$('#formID').find("input").each(function(index) {
    fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
    var namePart;
    if(fieldName.indexOf('_') > -1){
        namePart = fieldName.split("_");
        console.log(obj[namePart[0]][namePart[1]])
    }
    else{
        namePart = fieldName;
        console.log(obj[namePart])
    }

});
```

*Note: The property is not anonymous. If your run  `obj["propertyName"]` on an object with no such property it will return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry about that I misunderstood the question. What you are looking for is something like this.

```
var obj = {
    name: "student",
    contact: {
        phone: "22222",
        fax: "33333"
    }
};

$('#formID').("input").each(function(index) {
    fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
    var namePart = fieldName.split("_");

    var arbitraryVal = obj;
    for (var part in namePart) {
        if (arbitraryVal.hasOwnProperty(namePart[part])) {
            arbitraryVal = arbitraryVal[namePart[part]];
            continue;
        }
        arbitraryVal = null;
        break;
    }

    if (typeof $(this).val(arbitraryVal) !== 'undefined') {
        $(this).val(arbitraryVal);
    }
});
```

recusivly searches an object for each name part. If the name part is 
`contact_phone` It will look for `obj.contact.phone`  if it is `something_else_with_lots_of_underscores` it will look for `obj.something.else.with.lots.of.underscores`

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/csjxtmy6/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need to access any **arbitrary** property from that obj. Not just `contact`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form ID="formID">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="text" name="contact_phone" />
        <input type="text" name="contact_fax" />
    </form>  

    $("#formID").find("input").each(function() {
        fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
        namePart = fieldName.split("_");
         if(namePart.length ==1 && namePart[0]=="name"){
             $(this).val(obj.name);
         }
         else if(namePart.length>1){
             $(this).val(obj[namePart[0]][namePart[1]]);
         }
        //I want something like this: console.log(obj.namePart[0].namePart[1])
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/57vL6b0w/